# Htaccess rewrite error: Forward slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one RewriteRule in my .htaccess file that is causing me problem.

Rewrite rule format

> RewriteRule pattern target

The problem happen when there is a Forward slash (/) in the pattern. It seems like the server interpret it as a directory and because of that the target is run from that particular directory (that do not actually exist). This cause a 500 error on the server.

My .htaccess code is a follow:

```
RewriteRule ^store/women-shoes$ controller?controller=page&action=store&category=women-shoes
```

This cause a 500 error. This is the exact error I get in the apache error log.

> [Sat Mar 22 15:12:58 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded
>   the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration
>   error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if
>   necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

However if I remove the forward slash in the pattern, everything works fine so it shows me that the error come from the forward slash.

```
RewriteRule ^store-women-shoes$ controller?controller=page&action=store&category=women-shoes
```

The controller file is in the same directoy as the .htaccess file and it must remain that way. How can I update my code to keep the same format (with the forward slash in the pattern) but without triggering this 500 error. I need to tell the server: "Hey this is not a real directory, just the way the url is formatted)

Comment: Please don't open duplicate questions. You just asked the same question an hour ago.

Comment: Apparently you deleted the other one. Honestly it doesn't help to get your question answered faster to remove it and post it again with an hour. You have to be patient. Now you can tell it to check to see if the directory or file is not real using `REQUEST_FILENAME`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from another rules in my htaccess file, the following one:

```
# No extension act like .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```